# values entered by slider into forms are not saved unless manually entered into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

been trying to solve this for a couple days, when I am choosing a value using the slider and click quote, the values don't get saved unless I click into the forms and click on a key or the keyboard, then they get saved and displayed when I click on the quote. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, please help. this is such a headache.

https://jsfiddle.net/p58s0dpr/

all the relevant code is in the html tag, the js is a simple-slider from loopj.com.

```
<script>
        $("[data-slider]")
            .each(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            //$("<span>")
            //  .addClass("output")
            //  .insertAfter($(this));
            })
            .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
            $(this)
                $("#bitcoin").val(data.value.toFixed(6));
                $("#cad").val(((data.value.toPrecision(4)*1209.60).toFixed(2)));
            });
            </script>

<input id="bitcoin" type="form" placeholder="0.002 to 0.08" maxlength="8" pattern="\d*\.\d*" onchange="bitcoinCheck(this);">Bitcoin</input>

                <script>
                    function bitcoinCheck(input) {
                        if (input.value < 0.002) input.value = 0.002;
                        if (input.value > 0.08) input.value = 0.08;
                    }
                </script>

<p id="btc-amount">

                <script>
                    document.getElementById('bitcoin').onkeyup = function() {
                    if (this.value < 0.002) this.value = 0.002;
                    if (this.value > 0.08) this.value = 0.08;
                    var bitcoin = (this.value);
                    document.getElementById("btc-amount").innerHTML = "BTC amount requested: " +bitcoin;
                    }
                </script>

            </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onkeyup` listens for a key release; that's why your values update when you use your keyboard.

You need to attach a click event to your quote button for the behaviour you desire. This can be done with jQuery:

```
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
  var coinAmount = $('#bitcoin').val(),
      coinContent = 'BTC amount requested: ' + coinAmount,
  dollarAmount = $('#cad').val(),
  dollarContent = 'Market: $' + dollarAmount;

  $('#btc-amount').html(coinContent);
  $('#cad-quote').html(dollarContent);
});
```